# Adding a ValueChangeListener to CustomComponent

Tags: java, vaadin, valuechangelistener

I have a custom component and want to add a ValueChangeListener to it.
But I have a problem with the registration method.

This is my custom component.

```
public class CustomComp extends CssLayout implements HasValue<HashMap<String, Boolean>>{

private String value;

@Override
    public void setValue(String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.value = value;

    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Registration addValueChangeListener(com.vaadin.data.HasValue.ValueChangeListener<String> listener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Value Changed");
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void setRequiredIndicatorVisible(boolean requiredIndicatorVisible) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRequiredIndicatorVisible() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReadOnly(boolean readOnly) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadOnly() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


}
```

I want to create a object of my component and add a ValueChangeEvent like this but I think that I have to change the addValueChangeListener but I don´t know exactly how. I know that the method is called because the sysout "Value changed" is executed. But I want to add the listener like this.

```
MyCustomComp myCustomComp = new MyCustomComp();
myCustomComp.addValueChangeEvent(event ->{...});
```

I have already looked in other classes but this is different on every class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`CustomField`](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-customfield.html). It already implements `addValueChangeEvent` from `HasValue`, you just need to provide method to set and get value. Just remember to set your value with `setValue` method, otherwise fire value change event won't be fired.

Example:

```
class CustomComp extends CustomField<String> {

    private String value;

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doSetValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    protected Component initContent() {
        Button updateCurrentTimeBtn = new Button("Update current time");
        updateCurrentTimeBtn.addClickListener(event -> {
            setValue(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        });
        return updateCurrentTimeBtn;
    }

}
```

and usage:

```
Label currentTime = new Label();
currentTime.setCaption("Current time:");
addComponent(currentTime);

CustomComp customComp = new CustomComp();
customComp.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
    currentTime.setValue(customComp.getValue());
});
addComponent(customComp);
```